# Can SATA ports on a motherboard be different versions?

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard, sata

I want to swap the optical drive in my laptop with a HDD and for this I want to make sure that I can connect it to the motherboard via SATA3 for maximum efficiency.

I currently have a SSD that is connected with SATA3 and the optical drive connected with SATA1 and my question is: by swapping the optical drive with a brand new HDD, can I use the maximum SATA version of the motherboard, or is the port bound to the first version? If that is the case, is there any way that I can make use of the one SATA3 port in order to connect both the devices?

I used SiSoftware Sandra application to inspect the capabilities of my motherboard and this is what it says: 
[image: http://prntscr.com/f85cu0]

Also, does the cable influence the speed in any way? (Will I need to replace it as well in the scenario where the port supports SATA3?)

Motherboard model: X550VX

Comment: The SATA ports have a hardwired max.  You can have 2 different ports with different max, but you have to physically move the SSD to the other bay to take advantage of it.

Comment: Using a cable that does not support the highest transfer rate that both the port and the drive support is not supported and has caused serious corruption. DO NOT DO IT. Cables cannot negotiate.

Comment: "Can SATA ports on a motherboard be different versions?" - Yes; Older motherboards did this

Comment: Anecdote : My Asus ROG Maximus VII allowed me to choose between different SATA speeds for every port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having one SATA I device in the same system as a SATA III device should not affect the speed of the SATA III device.

My PC has a SATA II optical drive and two SATA III SSDs. The SSDs run at the full 6Gbps link rate while the optical drive runs at the slower 3Gbps speed.

---

Changing the SATA I device you are using over to a SATA III device should allow the higher link rate to be used. The controller can probably support 6Gbps on both ports, but is slowing down the one the optical drive is using because the drive cannot handle the speed.

By plugging in a higher speed device to that port instead it should renegotiate for a higher speed.

However as pointed out in the comments you need to make sure that the cabling is rated for the higher speeds. Given that the device you have appears to be a laptop, it's hard to say whether this is the case because there will either be some form of cabling (which maybe can be replaced if needed), or it the SATA connection is part of the motherboard itself.